# Spring MVC 3.1 - RedirectAttributes not part of model after redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm looking to develop a Spring MVC application that incorporates the POST/Redirect/GET pattern and input validation.  In the POST phase, I execute a Validator and get back a BindingResult/Errors collection.  If there are errors, I'd like to redirect back to the form with my validation errors in tact.  I want this to be a redirect that resolves as a GET request as to avoid expired caches and form resubmission prompts when using the browser's navigation buttons (back, forward, refresh).

This is how I'm handling the initial form display and is where I want to redirect the user back to if there are validation errors.

```
@RequestMapping("/account/list")
public String listAccounts(HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, Object> map) {

    log.debug("start of list accounts");

    map.put("accountList", entityService.listAccounts());
    map.put("account", new Account());
    map.put("accountTypeValues", AccountTypes.values());

//      Map<String, ?> inputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
//      if (inputFlashMap != null) {
//          map.putAll(inputFlashMap);
//      }

    return "account";
}
```

This is a snippet of the method that processes the POST:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addAccount(@ModelAttribute("account") @Valid Account account, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, Object> model) {
    accountValidator.validate(account, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("account", account);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "account", result);
        return "redirect:/account/list";
    }
```

I can see the FlashMap in the HttpServletRequest object at the end of the addAccount method and again after the redirect in the listAccounts method.  However, that map is never merged with the Model in listAccounts.  If I uncomment the inputFlashMap bit in listAccounts, then I get the desired results.

Why aren't the RedirectAttributes (aka FlashMap) merged into the Model after the redirect?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

The method listAccounts needs @ModelAttribute("account") Account account in the params like addAccount

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to worry about caching POST requests. Because POST requests should not been chached at all.

So it it valid to return the input form in response of an invalid POST request.

Comment: You're missing the part where I don't want the POST page to be included in the browser's history; the back/forward button.  If the user navigates to a page that was generated with a POST and caching is disabled, the browser will either give them a page expired message or will prompt them to resubmit the information.  That is undesirable.

Comment: When i set session attribute before redirecattributes it is not working. with out redirectAttributes it is working fine

Comment: @muthu: I can not connect your statement with this question or answer.

Comment: Sorry please help me to solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852921/spring-redirectattributes-clears-session-after-redirect

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the desired behavor by adding

```
@SessionAttributes("account")
```

to your controller instead of using flash scope. However, in this case you need to take care about removing attribute from the session when needed.