# Spring RedirectAttributes clears session after redirect

Tags: spring, redirect, spring-mvc

In my Spring i have used RedirectAttributes to display the message after login success or failure
and i have one SessionAttribute. I set SessionAttributes in two  times first one is when i click the menu
i set Object to SessionAttribute and second one is after login success
what my problem is the SessionAttribute which i set after login success is not working if i remove the
RedirectAttributes means it is working fine.

when i searched i found this

```
addFlashAttribute actually stores the attributes in a flashmap (which is internally maintained in the 
users session and removed once the next redirected request gets fulfilled)
```

when i debug it alwys shows the default one not show the value set after login.

this is for login

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/sample-client", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getClient(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
       Client client = createClient(userName, password);
        if (client != null) {
            model.addAttribute("clientObject", client);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Logined Successfully");
            return "redirect:" + "/sample/user";
        } else {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", "true");
            return "redirect:" + "/sample/login";
        }
    }

after login 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/byName", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String getUserByName(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("clientObject") User user) {
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        Integer page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
        return sample.getUserSearchByName(user, firstName, lastName, page);
    }
```

when i checked the clientObject here it shows the default one.